# encoding of RTF file

Tags: microsoft-word, rtf

I got RTF file created via Crystal Reports but text looks like (èìôåï)  - it seems to be encoding problem . Is there a way to change encoding ?  ( I did not find in font formatting something helpful )

Answer (score 1):

The encoding is probably UTF-8. You can use [iconv](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm) to convert it to something else such as CP1252.